# latex makefile not finding png: make: *** No rule to make target `pngfigure.pdf', needed by `main.pdf'. Stop

Tags: makefile, latex, pdflatex

I'm having trouble getting one of my documents to compile. I've used this makefile before no problems. However, this time, It seems to have a problem recognising .png figures and tries to load them as .pdf.

main.tex

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}  % Comment this line out
                                                          % if you need a4paper
%\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, conference]{ieeeconf}      % Use this line for a4
                                                          % paper

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts                              % This command is only
                                                          % needed if you want to
                                                          % use the \thanks command
\overrideIEEEmargins
% See the \addtolength command later in the file to balance the column lengths
% on the last page of the document

% The following packages can be found on http:\\www.ctan.org
\usepackage{graphics} % for pdf, bitmapped graphics files
\usepackage{epsfig} % for postscript graphics files
\usepackage{mathptmx} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
\usepackage{times} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
\usepackage{amsmath} % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{amssymb}  % assumes amsmath package installed

\usepackage{graphicx}   % Include figures
\usepackage{float}      % Include figures

\graphicspath{{./Figures/}} %Where the figures folder is located

\title{\LARGE \bf
.
.
.
\begin{document}
.
.
.
\begin{figure}[thpb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=3in]{pngfigure}
  \caption{pngfigure}
  \label{fig:pngfigure}
\end{figure}
.
.
.
```

and my Makefile

```
# Makefile for LaTeX files

LATEX   = pdflatex
BIBTEX  = bibtex
MAKEINDEX = makeindex

OUTPUT_PDF_FILE_NAME = phd_conversion_report
RERUN = "(There were undefined references|Rerun to get (cross-references|the bars) right)"
RERUNBIB = "No file.*\.bbl|Citation.*undefined"
MAKEIDX = "^[^%]*\\makeindex"
MPRINT = "^[^%]*print"
USETHUMBS = "^[^%]*thumbpdf"

SRC := $(shell egrep -l '^[^%]*\\begin\{document\}' *.tex)
BIBFILE := $(shell perl -ne '($$_)=/^[^%]*\\bibliography\{(.*?)\}/;@_=split /,/;foreach $$b (@_) {print "$$b.bib "}' $(SRC))

PDFPICS := $(shell perl -ne '@foo=/^[^%]*\\(includegraphics)(\[.*?\])?\{(.*?)\}/g;if (defined($$foo[2])) { if ($$foo[2] =~ /.pdf$$/) { print "$$foo[2] "; } else { print "$$foo[2].pdf "; }}' *.tex)
DEP = *.tex

TRG = $(SRC:%.tex=%.pdf)

COPY = if test -r $(<:%.tex=%.toc); then cp $(<:%.tex=%.toc) $(<:%.tex=%.toc.bak); fi 
RM = rm -f
OUTDATED = echo "EPS-file is out-of-date!" && false


all: $(TRG) copy clean

define run-latex
      $(COPY);$(LATEX) $<
      egrep -q $(MAKEIDX) $< && ($(MAKEINDEX) $(<:%.tex=%);$(COPY);$(LATEX) $<) ; true
      egrep -c $(RERUNBIB) $(<:%.tex=%.log) && ($(BIBTEX) $(<:%.tex=%);$(COPY);$(LATEX) $<) ; true
      egrep -q $(RERUN) $(<:%.tex=%.log) && ($(COPY);$(LATEX) $<) ; true
      egrep -q $(RERUN) $(<:%.tex=%.log) && ($(COPY);$(LATEX) $<) ; true
      if cmp -s $(<:%.tex=%.toc) $(<:%.tex=%.toc.bak); then true ;else $(LATEX) $< ; fi
      $(RM) $(<:%.tex=%.toc.bak)
      # Display relevant warnings
      egrep -i "(Reference|Citation).*undefined" $(<:%.tex=%.log) ; true
endef

$(TRG): %.pdf: %.tex $(DEP) $(PDFPICS) $(BIBFILE)
      @$(run-latex); \

PHONY: copy
copy:
      cp $(TRG:%.pdf=%.pdf) $(OUTPUT_PDF_FILE_NAME).pdf

.PHONY: clean
clean:
      -rm -f $(TRG) $(PSF) $(TRG:%.pdf=%.aux) $(TRG:%.pdf=%.bbl) $(TRG:%.pdf=%.blg) $(TRG:%.pdf=%.log) $(TRG:%.pdf=%.out); \
        $(RM) *.toc *.lot *.lof *.log Sections/*.aux Sections/*.fls Sections/*.log Sections/*.fdb*; \

.PHONY: cleanpdf
cleanpdf:
      -rm -f $(TRG) $(PSF) $(PDF) $(TRG:%.pdf=%.aux) $(TRG:%.pdf=%.bbl) $(TRG:%.pdf=%.blg) $(TRG:%.pdf=%.log) $(TRG:%.pdf=%.out); \
        $(RM) *.toc *.lot *.lof Sections/*.aux Sections/*.fls Sections/*.log Sections/*.fdb*; \
        $(RM) $(OUTPUT_PDF_FILE_NAME).pdf; \

.PHONY: view
view:
    acroread $(TRG:%.pdf=%.pdf)

.PHONY: osx
osx:
    open $(TRG:%.pdf=%.pdf)

.PHONY: count
count:
    texcount main.tex   

######################################################################
# Define rules for PDF source files.
.PHONY: pdf
%.pdf: %.eps
    epstopdf $< > $(<:%.eps=%.pdf)
```

Running make, I get the error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `pngfigure.pdf', needed by `main.pdf'.  Stop.
```

If I run

```
$ pdflatex main.tex
```

It compiles fine and the images show up. The error only happens with make.

Also, as an add on to this question, in the makefile I use texcount to count the words, I couldn't figure out how to get it to load the main.tex file no matter what it was called. I had to resort to the actual filename. I think it should be something like

```
texcount %.tex
```

But that doesn't work

Comment: Your `PDFPICS` macro takes the value in the `includegraphics` and spits out `$val.pdf`. Is that what you want? Or do you want `$val.png`? Or something else?

Comment: Basically I don't know why its not compiling. This makefile works on my other document. I am beginning to suspect it is to do with the .cls file which is in the template I am using here [link](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/preparation-of-papers-for-ieee-sponsored-conferences-and-symposia/zfnqfzzzxghk#.VdVA6lOqpBc). But I am not sure. It certainly does look like a Makefile problem

Comment: Does it work on the same document on another machine? Because the issue is clearly that you are trying to automate dependencies but are not getting that right. Is `basic_biosensor_operation_diagram.png` correct? Or should that be `basic_biosensor_operation_diagram.pdf`? Or something else? Is that in an `includegraphics` directive (or whatever the term for that is)?

Comment: So if I change the line to have $val.png `PDFPICS := $(shell perl -ne '@foo=/^[^%]*\\(includegraphics)(\[.*?\])?\{(.*?)\}/g;if (defined($$foo[2])) { if ($$foo[2] =~ /.pdf$$/) { print "$$foo[2] "; } else { print "$$foo[2].png "; }}' *.tex)` I get the same error. `make: *** No rule to make target 'pngfigure.png', needed by main.pdf'. Stop.`

Comment: Is `pngfigure.png` correct? What does `\includegraphics[width=3in]{pngfigure}` refer to as a source file?

Comment: Yep works on other documents across computers. Just not on this document. The file is a .png file. Located in ./Figures/pngfigure.PNG

Comment: Then that needs to output `Figures/$$foo[2].png` or whatever the correct path is. The problem is that you aren't generating the prerequisite correctly for that file. Looks like you'll need to incorporate looking for `\graphicspath` to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `pngfigure.pdf', needed by `main.pdf'.  Stop.
```

means that you listed `pngfigure.pdf` as a prerequisite of `main.pdf` but that make doesn't know how to build that.

It doesn't know how to build that, presumably, because it isn't actually a pdf file (or a tex file that can be converted to a pdf file).

The incorrect prerequisite here is coming from the `PDFPICS` macro which is finding all the `\includegraphics` entries in the tex file and then spitting out `$name.pdf` for them. Clearly, at least in that case that is incorrect.

Additionally, simply updating the `PDFPICS` macro to use `png` instead of `pdf` is not enough if the images are not in the current directory (as they appear not to be in this case).

For that you'll need to incorporate parsing of `\graphicspath` from the document as well to include that in the `PDFPICS` generated prerequisites.